# Configure Structuremap IOC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Hello Experts I have class in folowing structure

```
public class Apple:IApple
{
  public IBall _ball{get;private set}

  public Apple()
 {
  _ball=new Ball();
 }
}

Public class Cat:ICat
{
  private readonly IBall _ball;

  Public Cat(IBall ball)
  {
    this._ball=ball
  }
}
```

I am configuring my structure map as below (Not displayed standard registry and controller registry with controller conventions)

```
ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.For<IApple>().Use<Apple>();
            cfg.For<ICat>.Use<Cat>(); 

        });
```

When I reference ICat in Controller as below

```
    private readonly ICat _cat;

    public HomeController(ICat cat)
    {
        this._cat = cat;
    }
```

I am receiving error "No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type IBall".

Experts, please provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register `IBall` like this:

```
cfg.For<IBall>().Use(c =>   ((Apple)c.GetInstance<IApple>())._ball);
```